# Center radio button with input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have some custom radio buttons. The final option should be a radio button with an input field.
As you can see, in de Codepen example, the radio button does not align vertically center with the input field.
I have tried everything from calculating top, to display flex.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/monsmado/pen/RwarYEG

```
<form>
    <label>Do you have an elevator?</label>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="elevatorYes" name="elevator" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="elevatorYes">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="elevatorNo" name="elevator" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="elevatorNo">No</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="elevatorOther" name="elevator" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="elevatorOther">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="elevator" placeholder="Other">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS in this case

```
.form-group:nth-child(4) .custom-control-label:after, .form-group:nth-child(4) .custom- control-label:before{
 margin-top: 0.5em
}
```

I send you the solution in you codepen

https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/qBZbJaZ

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about! Thanks for the example and your help.

Comment: This falls apart when you change the font size (although so do the other lines)

Answer (score 1):

Well, a quick fix for your situation could be overriding the current top value of the custom radio button and set it to `25%` *(Since the actual height of it is `50%` of your input so the `25%` will fit it exactly in middle)*. Also, note that display flex on the parent element won't work as expected because the customized radio exits within the `::before` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements#:%7E:text=A%20CSS%20pseudo%2Delement%20is,of%20every%20element.) so it won't get the flex attribute.

```css
.custom-control-label[for=monthsOther]::before,
.custom-control-label[for=monthsOther]::after {
  top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <label>How many months?</label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="monthsYes" name="months" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="monthsYes">1-2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="monthsNo" name="months" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="monthsNo">3-5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="monthsOther" name="months" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="monthsOther">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="months" placeholder="Other">
        </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind since the radio button itself and its background on check action is defined in `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements you need to override both of them.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. I'll try some other solutions and might even go with giving it's own class to be able to position the radio button for last option.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a really hacky way to change the appearance of form elements. The original question is missing any CSS code (which is where all the problems arise) but the linked codepen does show the root causes. It will be very difficult to properly align elements that are absolutely positioned, especially when you start taking left-to-right or larger font sizes into account. Additionally, creating the visual representation of a radio button using a `::before` on inside the label is a recipe for frustration and ultimately a bad solution.

The proper solution is probably using `vertical-align: middle` or `vertical-align: baseline` on both the radio and the label. but those will have no effect while the elements are absolutely positioned.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4.5 with their custom fields. So if it's 'hacky' I'll leave that up to the devs of Bootstrap.

I've tried it with flex and vertical alignment but as you mentioned it uses the ::before and ::after pseudo elements to style the radio buttons.

Comment: What's crazy to me is the radio button visual is coming from the label and not the radio button element itself. Without bootstrap, the radio buttons don't get larger when the font size is increased. With bootstrap, they increase in size but the position isn't consistent. If you end up writing a lot of custom code to deal with these normal cases, I'm not sure what you're getting from the framework aside from the unnecessary battle. It's also kind of strange the text box is inside the label element; it doesn't even work properly in chrome; the radio doesn't get selected but highlights on click.

Comment: I don't know what's so wrong about that though. Even material design uses the same principal: https://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html and https://material.io/components/selection-controls
Perhaps it's a bug or mistake in Bootstrap where they don't align properly. Having the text box inside the label element was my doing in order to get it in-line with the radio button which I've changed in production.

Comment: I wouldn't give material design a pass; I think they are bending over backwards to make something I personally and professionally feel are objectively bad designs both visually and usably. There's certainly a weak point in web styling around input controls. Alternatively, you can make your own Web Component however you see fit without having to work within the constraints of the input controls; but you would be taking on a huge task if you wanted to incorporate accessibility among other things.